# Highcharts stock chart time selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm working with a highcharts stock chart [similar to this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/styling/).  My chart has hundreds of data points.  Is there any way to progamatically pre-set the time slider below the chart?

Let's assume my X-Axis has 100 data points (datetime, grouped on seconds).  I'd like the default view of the chart to have the selector to show 20 points.  Points 40-60

This is the sample I'm working with:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        rangeSelector: {
            buttonTheme: { // styles for the buttons
                fill: 'none',
                stroke: 'none',
                'stroke-width': 0,
                r: 8,
                style: {
                    color: '#039',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                    },
                    select: {
                        fill: '#039',
                        style: {
                            color: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                    // disabled: { ... }
                }
            },
            inputBoxBorderColor: 'gray',
            inputBoxWidth: 120,
            inputBoxHeight: 18,
            inputStyle: {
                color: '#039',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            labelStyle: {
                color: 'silver',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltsc/qpsjbcdL/4/), the StockChart is being plotted with 300 points. Next the timestamp of point[40] and [60] are being retrieved and [`setExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes) is called to set the min and max timestamp of bottom navigator.